# Qual è una buona traduzione per Buzzword?

Tags: translation

Nel mio ambito lavorativo (informatica) mi scontro spesso con persone che parlano molto per buzzword, parole di moda.
Qualche esempio: big-data, cognitive, smart, data-science.

Come posso tradurre il termine "buzzword" in italiano, in un modo vagamente dispregiativo ma rapido e sopratutto comprensibile anche ai miei colleghi che non conoscono il termine inglese?

EDIT:

Ecco un esempio di contesto (puramente inventato) in cui l'uso sostenuto della terminologia di moda rende necessario esprimere il concetto di "buzzword" in maniera dispregiativa:

> Come per tutte le *Fintech* di successo, il *business model* della nostra *startup* si basa su una *UIX* *customer* centrica e una riduzione dei costi ottenuta tramite l'adozione di algoritmi *cognitive*, basati sulle ultime tecnologie *big-data*, grazie al lavoro dei nostri migliori *data scientists*.

Leggendo una frase simile la commenteri:

> Spero che dietro a tutte quelle buzzword lui sappia anche quello che sta dicendo!

Ci tengo a precisare che considero positivamente l'uso di terminologia tecnica (anche inglese), ma in certi casi mi ritrovo a incespicare in frasi eccessive.

Comment: Buona domanda! Solo per curiosità, il Ragazzini dà “termine in voga; parola che va di moda”, che è una spiegazione, non una traduzione.

Comment: @DaG - in realtà quello è il significato e quindi anche una valida la traduzione in italiano. Da Garzanti: ◊ *privatization is now a worldwide buzz word* ; privatizzazione è attualmente una parola di moda in tutto il mondo.

Comment: Certo che quello è il significato, @Gio, ma questo non ne fa automaticamente una traduzione. Tradurresti *house* con “manufatto in cui risiedono esseri umani”?

Comment: @DaG - che c'entra? Buzzword è la parola di moda, di tendenza del momento. That's it.

Comment: Forse "tormentone" si potrebbe usare in questo caso, anch se  in genere si dice più comunemente di frasi o battute ripetute spesso in ambito giornalistico o televisivo.

Comment: @Gio, a parte la tua opinione in particolare su *buzzword*, ti è chiara la differenza fra definire una parola e tradurla?

Comment: @DaG forse non è chiaro a te che non tutti i termini sono traducibili con altri termini. Ci sono espressioni che richiedono più di una parola. Questo è uno di quei casi.

Comment: @Gio, facciamo che smettiamo entrambi di essere paternalistici?

Comment: Federico, è chiaro che cosa vuol dire *buzzword*, ma potresti fare un esempio, anche inventato, di frase in cui ti potrebbe capitare di usarlo, per partire da un caso concreto?

Comment: @DaG - nessun paternalismo da parte mia, solo una questione di chiarezza.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65480/discussion-between-dag-and-gio).

Comment: Grazie Gio e DaG. Non sono contrario all'uso di una rapida spiegazione, ma in questo caso "termine in voga" o "parola che va di moda" non esprimono il sentimento (leggermente) negativo che attribuisco invece a _buzzword_. "Tormentone" si avvicina di più in effetti.

Comment: "Anglicismo" è un termine un po' generico, "tecno-anglicismo" per racchiudere solo l'ambito tecnico informatico. In modo un po' dispregiativo si potrebbe usare la locuzione "delirio di tecno-anglicismi"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non mi viene in mente una traduzione esatta 1:1, ma nel tuo esempio mi sembra che vada benissimo l'accrescitivo "parolone":

> Spero che dietro a tutte quelle **parolone** lui sappia anche quello che sta dicendo!

Un'altra espressione idiomatica dal significato collegato è *riempirsi la bocca* (con certi paroloni).

Comment: mi piace "parolone" in questo contesto

Comment: Domanda interessa. Parole gergali. Questa potrebbe essere una valida traduzione anche se viene a mancare, almeno in parte, la connotazione dispregiativa, perlomeno quella che ho in mente io e, credo, anche lei. Mi sembra uno dei casi dove l uso dell'inglese è corretto. A meno che già non ci sia davvero un termine italiano. Ad esempio, come definire jobs act, ticket, question time? Buzzwords? Prese in giro? Paroloni?

Comment: Mi piace questa risposta, specialmente perché lo stesso termine "buzzword" è spesso usato come una buzzword! "Parolona" esiste da tempo immemorabile e suona molto "italiana". Le frasi ripiene di anglismi usate da certe persone ricordano i "latinorum" (qui suggerito da qualcun'altro) usato a suo tempo dal clero con i popolani con lo stesso scopo: apparire inaccessibili, dire niente con parole oscure.

Answer (score 3):

Aggiungo anche la proposta [supercazzola](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercazzola).

Answer (score 1):

Aggiungerei anche: *Latinorum*. Per quanto non effettivamente usato.

La frase verrebbe:

> Spero che dietro a tutto quel *Latinorum* lui sappia anche quello che
> sta dicendo!

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Cosa vuoi dire con "non effettivamente usato"? E, poi, un "latinorum" non sarebbe un discorso oscuro, non necessariamente composto di parole alla moda?

Comment: - Cosa vuoi dire con "non effettivamente usato"? che e un'espressione presa dai 'Promessi Sposi' di manzoni. Tutti l'hanno almeno sentita e capiscono cosa significa, ma non la trovo veramente usata nel linguaggio comune.
- "latinorum" non sarebbe un discorso oscuro, non necessariamente composto di parole alla moda? eheh, non proprio: 'latinorum' indica proprio parole in latino, buttate li in mezzo al discorso per darsi un tono. Cambiati i tempi, metti l'inglese al posto del latino e hai i buzzwords.

Comment: puoi trovare di piu qui: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/latinorum/

Answer (score 0):

"Anglicismo" è un termine un po' generico, "tecno-anglicismo" per racchiudere solo l'ambito tecnico informatico. In modo un po' dispregiativo si potrebbe usare la locuzione "delirio di tecno-anglicismi"...

Comment: A parte che “anglesismo” non esiste (c'è un'ampia scelta fra “anglismo”, “anglicismo” e “inglesismo”), la domanda non riguarda specificamente gli anglismi. Una *buzzword* potrebbe benissimo essere costituita da un termine italiano.

Comment: Hai ragione, anglicismo... correggo.

Comment: Sono io che ho dato il voto negativo e dal mio commento si evince il perché: mi scuso per non aver collegato esplicitamente le due cose.

Comment: Ho risposto anche sul Meta.

Comment: Molto severa come reazione, tenuto conto che il suo commento richiamava una estensione del concetto. Grazie comunque del chiarimento di pensiero

Comment: Grazie per la comprensione, @ealy. Giusto per spiegarmi meglio, non è un fatto di severità: è solo che, per usare l'esempio posto dall'OP, non credo che “Spero che dietro a tutti quegli anglicismi lui sappia anche quello che sta dicendo!” renda l'idea cercata, visto che lui stesso specifica che non ha niente contro la terminologia inglese in quanto tale, ma solo contro i termini troppo di moda (o comunque vogliamo chiamarli).

Comment: Come ho spiegato nel meta, tecno-anglicismi. Anglicismo da solo l'ho detto brevemente nella risposta che è troppo generico. Per cui "spero che dietro a tutti quei tecno-anglicismi lui sappia quel che dice" non mi pare una così fuorviante castroneria. Accetto comunque la sua opinione

Comment: Un voto negativo non designa una “fuorviante castroneria”, ma solo una risposta che – nell'opinione di chi vota – non centra la questione. Libero l'OP o altri di votare positivamente la risposta, se ritengono che renda l'idea. Grazie per aver a tua volta (qui usa darsi del tu) approfondito il tuo ragionamento, e spero anch'io che continuerai a frequentare utilmente questo sito.

Comment: Grazie @DaG per aver risposto alla domanda sul Meta!